# httpclient exception handling

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin, httpclient

I am handing `HttpRequestException` when I use `PostAsync` and it works fine, but when I am trying to handle same exception on `GetAsync` it throws `TaskCanceledException a task was cancelled` with a long timeout instead. How do I make `GetAsync` throw `HttpRequestException`?

```
  public async Task<bool> AddQrCodeToRequest(int projectId, int requestId, string code, string token)
    {
        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { code });
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(CreateExceptionDescription(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()));
        }
    }

    public async Task<List<string>> GetUpdatedQrCodesList(Request request, string token)
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        var result = await client.GetAsync(url);
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var requestsJson = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(requestsJson);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(CreateExceptionDescription(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()));
        }
    }
```

handling post

```
try
{
     string QrCode = result.Text;
     if (await restService.AddQrCodeToRequest(Request, result.Text, Vars.User.Token))
     {
          QrCodes.Add(QrCode);
          await DisplayAlert("Code added", QrCode, "OK");
     }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     if (ex is HttpRequestException)
     {
           //network ex handling
     }
     else
     {
           //other handling
     }
}
```

handling get (app crashes after timeout)

```
        try
        {
            UpdatedQrCodes = await restService.GetUpdatedQrCodesList(Request, Vars.User.Token);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is HttpRequestException)
            {
                //never thrown
            }
            else
            {
                //never also thrown
            }
        }
```

Comment: Add code where you handled HttpRequestException and main method where you want this..

Comment: @AnkurTripathi added

Comment: If you want to force a particular exception then do a try/catch in the method that makes the request and throw out what you want. I don't really see the value in it though.

Comment: @Crowcoder it is not what I am looking for

Comment: @VladimirMarchenko well, you can't expect a certain exception because you want it that way, the code will throw what it throws.

Comment: @Crowcoder What I am asking is why PostAsync throws HttpRequestException immediately and GetAsync is throwing TaskCanceledException after a long timeout and how to work aroud it

Comment: @VladimirMarchenko POST would throw the same exception if it were timing out too. As to why your GET request is timing out, it is impossible to say. Are you asking how to work around the exception or the timeout? If timeout, you could use the overload that accepts a CancelationToken and set the timeout to be shorter but I don't know if that solves any problem for you.

Comment: @Crowcoder I want GetAsync throw HttpRequestException as PostAsync does when there is no internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround use nuget `Xamarin.Essentials` and before you execute your GET check if there's internet available:

```
var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;

if (current == NetworkAccess.Internet)
{
    // Connection to internet is available
}
```

Comment: I wonder if there is a better solution. Thanks for the workaround.

Comment: I like the solution. @VladimirMarchenko I don't think `getAsync` would throw `HttpRequestException`, here is the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpclient.getasync) . One thing I think of is you can check `IsCompleted` or alike then throw new exception yourself.